# Exception handling when assigning a variable C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, variables, variable-assignment

While working on a project, I realised that there's something I really don't know about C# (and I can't find anything about that on google either). If you assign a value to a variable (which has already been initialised with a default value), and the value is created by another method, what happens if you get an exception in the other method. For clarification, here an example:

```
eType = defaultvalue;
...
eType = (EReaderType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EReaderType), tXmlNode.InnerText, true);
```

What happens if Enum.Parse can't parse the value (string in a Xml, unimportant here...) and throws an exception? Will eType keep its default value, or will it be reassigned by something else (null or some undefined blabla)? So far, my tests show that it will keep the old value. However, I'm not sure if this will work all the time or if it was by accident. Simply said, I don't know how C# handles this stuff.

Edit: Ok, thanks a lot for all the answers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to reason about it is:

- side effects of *subexpressions* are executed from *left to right*.
- side effects of *operators* are executed in *precedence order*.

Suppose you have:

```
M().x = N(P()).Q(); // x is a variable
```

The order in which things happen is:

- M() is executed
- the location of x is determined
- P() is executed
- N() is executed
- Q() is executed
- the assignment to x happens

If one of those things throws an exception, then everything that happens after the exception is never performed.

Answer (score 18):

If you aren't sure if parsing will succeed, consider using [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) instead.

But in your example, the right-hand side must be completely evaluated before the assignment takes place, so an exception while processing the right-hand side will prevent the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Variable will keep its old value because actual eType = (computed value) operation wont be performed because it will throw an exception during process of computing that value ( parsing a string in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Think about it in terms of the *steps* involved.

If you have:

```
var x = SomeOperation();
```

This is what happens:

1. `SomeOperation` executes.
2. The return value is assigned to `x`.

If an exception is thrown within `SomeOperation`, then step 1 above does not reach completion. Which means step 2 is never reached.

This is a guaranteed, deterministic order of events as far as I know. So you needn't worry about `x` suddenly being assigned some unpredictable value.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know it would throw an exception during the second allocation, wich eventually will not save a new value, keeping the old one